# How to get gradients with respect to input and change input (rather than trainable vars) to minimize loss in TF 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, tensorflow2.0

I want to use a trained model to change the input so it minimizes the loss (rather than changing the trainable variables) a la Deep Dreaming in Tensorflow 2.0 but I am not having success.

Say I have a basic NN as the one in the docs

```
class MyModel(Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.flatten = Flatten()
    self.d1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')
    self.d2 = Dense(10, activation='softmax')

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)
    x = self.d1(x)
    return self.d2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

Which I train using a simple tf.GradientTape function

```
@tf.function
def train_step(image, label):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(image)
    loss = loss_object(label, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

What's the idiomatic way to create a function that will instead calculate and apply the gradients to the input - images.

I assumed it will be as simple as

```
def train_step(image, label):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(image)
    loss = loss_object(label, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, image)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, image))
```

However, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.GradientTape.gradients` can only differentiate wrt to a watched tensor. Variables are automatically watched on first access. In order to differentiate wrt an arbitrary tensor, you have to explicitly `watch` it:

```
>>> x = tf.constant([4.0])
>>> y = tf.constant([2.0])
>>> with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
...     tape.watch([x, y])
...     z = x * y
...     
>>> tape.gradient(z, [x, y])
[<tf.Tensor: id=9, shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 2.], dtype=float32)>, 
 <tf.Tensor: id=10, shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 4.], dtype=float32)>]
```

Comment: Adding `tape.watch([image])` at the start of `with tf.GradientTape() as tape:` in the above `modify_input` function just leads to 


`TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.`


And `tf.executing_eagerly() ` returns True (as this is 2.0). This seems to happen at `apply_gradients`

Comment: That might be happening because you call `tape.gradients` with a single tensor as a second argument, therefore the result is also a tensor and not a list of tensors. Change `tape.gradient(loss, image)` to `tape.gradient(loss, [image])`.

Comment: By the way, `tape.watch(image)` should work as well.

Comment: I cannot seem to make it work inside of a tf.function - mainly getting `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'` but curiously it works if it's not in a function. I had to pass `[image]` to `zip` and `tape.gradient` AND turn it into a tf.Variable beforehand (which is automatic in a tf.function but doesnt work even if I do it or if I dont with identical code).

Comment: Interesting. Could you open an issue on GitHub with a stracktrace and ideally a reproducer? http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Comment: In function actually works if you do `image = tf.Variable(image)` outside of the function (though you dont need that for e.g. just training or anything where you dont need its gradients. If you do it inside the function you get `ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.` which kind of makes sense.

Not sure if this qualifies as a bug or is just expected that some stuff need to always be done outside of `tf.functions`.

Comment: I am not sure why you need a variable to get it working. The `ValueError` is by design, no need to report it.

Comment: If you dont turn it into a tf.Variable, image becomes a `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>` and you get a `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'` at `apply_gradients`. However, you can't turn it into a Variable in the function.